# Django: "source bin/activate" has no effect

Tags: django, virtualenv

Sometimes `source bin/activate` has no effect, but other times it works. I wonder why this is happening?

See the attached figure. After `source bin/activate`, the prompt does show the virtual environment, but `which python` still shows that system command is used.

[image]

Comment: what is the value of your PATH environment variable? I think it's possible the PATH is not set up correctly.

Comment: OK, I found the problem: I moved the virtual environment somewhere else. Apparently, the path was set during the env's installation and it remains fixed. Moving the environment to other places requires re-installation. How inconvenient!

Comment: There is one command: `VIRTUAL_ENV="..."` which sets an absolute path for the virtual env.